Loop integral of $\mathbf{r}\times d\mathbf{r}$ is equal to twice the enclosed area?
I came across the following integral in the literature for a loop $l$ that goes around a surface of area $A$:
$$
\oint_l \mathbf{r}\times d\mathbf{r} = 2 A \mathbf{\hat{n}}
$$
where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is orthogonal to the surface.
Could someone please help me understand where this equation is coming from? I tried to parametrize $\mathbf{r}$ and do the integral for the simple example of a unit circle and I end up with the circumference instead of twice the area of that circle.

I strongly suggest you take a look at the Stokes formula. :)

The area should be a vector right?

We may compute $\mathbf r\times \mathrm d\mathbf r$ first:
$$\mathbf r\times \mathrm d\mathbf r=\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf i & \mathbf j & \mathbf k\\
x & y & 0\\
\mathrm dx & \mathrm dy & 0
\end{vmatrix}=(x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx)\mathbf k$$
Substituting in your integral we get
$$\oint_{\ell=\partial A}\mathbf r\times \mathrm d\mathbf r=\mathbf k\oint_{\partial A}x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx$$
And per Green's theorem,
$$\mathbf k\oint_{\partial A}x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx=\mathbf k\iint_A\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial y}\right)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=2\mathbf k\iint_A\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=2A \mathbf k=2\mathbf A$$

By using the very definition of the cross-product, one finds:
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
x& y & z \\
dx& dy & dz \\
\end{array}
\right| =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
ydz-zdy \\
zdx-xdz \\
xdy-ydx
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Using Stokes’ theorem and component-wise integration, one obtains:
$$
\oint_{l=\partial A} \mathbf{r} \times {d} \mathbf{r} = \int_{A} \Bbb d \{\mathbf{r} \times d\mathbf{r} \} =  \int_{A} \mathbb{d} \ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
ydz-zdy \\
zdx-xdz \\
xdy-ydx
\end{array}
\right] = 2
\int_{A}  \left[
\begin{array}{c}
dydz\\
dzdx \\
dxdy
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where in the last equation we used the skew symmetry of 2-forms and the property that $\Bbb{d}^2=0$. Now what we’ve got is nothing but integrals over projections over each axis:
$$
 2
\int_{A}  \left[
\begin{array}{c}
dydz\\
dzdx \\
dxdy
\end{array}
\right]= 2
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A_x\\
A_y \\
A_z
\end{array}
\right] = 2 \mathbf{A}
$$
